# How do I update part of a 3D texture efficiently?

Tags: opengl, raycasting

I am writing a voxel ray caster that implements a form of an N^3 tree.  The voxels are stored in a large chunk pool of size 1024^3 and is segmented into 32^3 chunks.  The chunk pool needs to be updated every frame either once or multiple times.

I have all the rendering working on sample data of a 3D texture I generated with a compute shader.  I just can’t seem to figure out how to update N^3 chunks of a 3D texture.

I have come across glMapBufferRange and glTexSubImage3D.  How do I efficiently stream portions of a 3D texture to the GPU?

Comment: Show us the code you made so far.

Comment: the chunk pool is just a 3d texture and the shaders are irrelevant to the question.  I haven't implemented any of the streaming yet because I have no idea how to update a 3d texture.

Comment: You can use glTexSubImage3D() or you can write to a 3D texture from a compute shader by binding a particular MIP level of a texture as an image with glBindImageTexture(). Then you use imageStore() inside the shader.

Comment: Do you ask how to update a 3D texture or how to update a texture efficiently? These are orthogonal things, being a 3D texture doesn't play a role in streaming the data.

Comment: thanks! yeah it seems glTexSubImage3D() will work for my purposes. IDK if it's the fastest way...I also don't think I can use MIP mapping since the chunks need a buffer around them if I want to use trilinear interpolation.